# How to use jQuery notification plugin in jQuery Validation submitHandler function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

In my form I have validation using jQuery Validate. After completing validation, success message should be shown using jQuery Notification plugin. My validation code is

```
  $("#validateForm").validate(
{
    debug: false,
    rules: 
    {
firstname: {
    required: true,
    lettersonly: true
},
lastname: {
    required: true,
    lettersonly: true
}

 },
 messages: {
firstname: {
    required: "Please enter your firstname"
},
lastname: {
    required: "Please enter your lastname"
}
    },
 submitHandler : function(msg){

    showNotification({
                        message: "hi",
                        type: "success",
                        autoClose: true,
                        duration: 5                                        
                    }); 

 },

});
```

After validation show notification message and disappear some interval. Am using this plugin http://demos.9lessons.info/jnotification/?type=error&message=This%20is%20sample%20PHP%20get%20parameters%20reading%20notification

After validating the field, the form has not display notificaton message. `showNotification()` function not working. How do you insert the notification function inside the `submitHandler()`?

Comment: Please be more clear as to what you need help with, what is your actual question?

Comment: After validating the field, the form has not display notificaton message.  showNotification() function not working. How to insert notification function inside the submitHandler().

Comment: Please be more careful when tagging your question.  The [tag:jquery-form-validator] plugin has nothing to do with the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin.  And neither does the [tag:html] tag when you're not asking us anything about HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea where you've even obtained the Show Notification plugin as [the page](http://demos.9lessons.info/demos/jnotification/) does not have any download links; it also appears to be many years old since it's using jQuery 1.4.  I cannot even setup a proper demo because you have not bothered to show us the relevant HTML.

However, there is absolutely nothing wrong with the jQuery Validate code you've shown us.

**Quote OP:**

> *"After validating the field, the form has not display notificaton message. `showNotification()` function not working. How do you insert the notification function inside the `submitHandler()`?"*

I think you may be misunderstanding how the `submitHandler` function works.  It only fires when you click the submit button AND then if/when all fields are valid.  It does not fire after each field is validated individually.

Otherwise, edit your question to include the relevant HTML markup of the form.

---

I see that you've renamed the `form` argument into `msg` for the `submitHandler` function.  Renaming it will not break it, however it demonstrates that you completely misunderstand what it represents.  The plugin developer has provided the `form` argument as a representation of the form object.  You can rename it whatever you wish, *but it's always going to represent the form object*.

```
submitHandler: function(form) { ...
```

---

**EDIT**:

As suspected, the `showNotification` plugin is horribly out of date.  In my jsFiddle below, you can see the green notification bar flicker and then a console error tells you that `.live()` (within `showNotification` plugin) is an undefined function.  (`.live()` has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and removed since jQuery 1.9)

**DEMO 1:  http://jsfiddle.net/9qenjr42/**

Downgrading to jQuery v1.8.3 shows that your code would have worked:  http://jsfiddle.net/9qenjr42/2/

**However, I don't recommend downgrading jQuery just to use an old plugin.**  Here are some suggestions...

- replace it with a modern and better maintained notification plugin
- ask the developer to update his plugin code for newer versions of jQuery
- update the plugin code yourself

Comment: @abdul, you're welcome, but using such an old version of jQuery is not a good idea.  You really should update the plugin code so you can use the latest version of jQuery.  Good luck.